# AngularJS : Calling controller events from directives

Tags: events, angularjs, handler, directive

Suppose you need to write a directive that takes one attribute-parameter - name of the controller's event function. The directive does some processing and then fires a notification on that event handler, passing it some processing parameters.

What would be a recommended way to set up such attribute in the directive to avoid unnecessary overhead, like two-way binding?

So far I was only able to achieve this by using two-way binding as shown in the example below:

```
app.controller("testCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.onClickEvent = function (ctrlDown) {
        alert(ctrlDown);
    }
});

app.directive("customInput", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            onClickNotify: "=onClick",
        },
        template: "<input type='text' ng-click='onClick()' />",
        replace: true,
        transclude: false,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            scope.onClick = function () {
                if (typeof (scope.onClickNotify) == 'function') {
                    scope.onClickNotify(window.event.ctrlKey);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

<custom-input on-click="onClickEvent" />
```

In the example above the directive uses "=" - bi-directional binding for the attribute, the only way I was able to make it work. What I cannot understand is why can't we use "&"? According to AngularJS documentation, we should be able to, while passing parameters with names, i.e. like this:

```
scope.onClickNotify({ctrlDown: window.event.ctrlKey});
```

But it just doesn't work. And if I try and specify parameters in the event name like this:

```
<custom-input on-click="onClickEvent(ctrlDown)" />
```

then it still doesn't work. Instead, the value I pass in the directive is ignored.

I'm confused as to what is really going on in the background and why doesn't it work with "&" as expected? Two-way binding does look like an overhead to me in this scenario, because we are just passing the function name in one direction, if not as a simple attribute (with "@").

And if I'm doing something wrong here, then what is the right way?

Comment: I just did the same in a simpler example, and it suddenly worked. Now I'm really confused. Will try to narrow down the differences. Still I would welcome any suggestions on the subject of a recommended way of passing event handlers into directives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it working using `&`. You are right. Creating a two-way binding is an overhead.

Actually you 're supposed to pass an object while calling the controller method:

```
app.directive("customInput", function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            onClickNotify: "&onClick",
        },
        template: "<input type='text' ng-click='onClick()' />",
        replace: true,
        transclude: false,          
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            scope.onClick = function () {
                if (typeof (scope.onClickNotify) == 'function') {
                    scope.onClickNotify({ctrlDown:"foo"});
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<custom-input on-click="onClickEvent(ctrlDown)" />
```

Comment: Yep, that works as supposed to. I may have missed something the first time, but it is a good guideline now for any newcomer when it comes to event handlers in AngularJS ;)